# SQL Substring \g

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I would just like to know where do I put the `\g` in this query?

```
SELECT project, 
SUBSTRING(address FROM 'A-Za-z') AS letters, 
SUBSTRING(address FROM '\d') AS numbers 
FROM repositories
```

I tried this but this brings back nothing (it doesn't throw an error though)

```
SELECT project, 
SUBSTRING(CONCAT(address, '#') FROM 'A-Za-z' FOR '#') AS letters, 
SUBSTRING(CONCAT(address, '#') FROM '\d' FOR '#') AS numbers 
FROM repositories
```

Here is an example: I would like the string `1DDsg6bXmh3W63FTVN4BLwuQ4HwiUk5hX` to return `DDsgbXmhWFTVNBLwuQHwiUkhX`. So basically return all the letters...and then my second one is to return all the numbers.

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Comment: Yes, BUT I would like to know if there is a solution that does not use any postgresql function

Comment: You should tell us what the `\g` is supposed to be doing.  I have used Postgres a bit, but I don't know off the top of my head what is happening.

Comment: So the regex will return the first match, `\g` is a way to make the regex return every match, instead of only the first match

Comment: So you basically want to apply a regex multiple times against a given string, and return every match?  Is that right?

Comment: Kind of yes, check out this link for a better explanation on the `\g` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Comment: The closest thing in Postgres to what you want might be `regexp_matches`, [see here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html).  But, this requires specifying multiple capture groups, which then get returned if found.  It would only return the same pattern however many times you enter it.  Maybe you should tell us why you need this functionality in a database context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177611/discussion-between-paul-kruger-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `g` (“global”) modifier in regular expressions indicates that *all* matches rather than only the first one should be used.

That doesn't make much sense in the `substring` function, which returns only a single value, namely the first match. So there is no way to use `g` with `substring`.

In those functions where it makes sense in PostgreSQL (`regexp_replace` and `regexp_matches`), the `g` can be specified in the optional last *flags* parameter.

If you want to find all substrings that match a pattern, use `regexp_matches`.

---

For your example, which really has nothing to do with `substring` at all, I'd use

```
SELECT translate('1DDsg6bXmh3W63FTVN4BLwuQ4HwiUk5hX', '0123456789', '');

         translate         
---------------------------
 DDsgbXmhWFTVNBLwuQHwiUkhX
(1 row)
```

Comment: I updated my question with an example. Would you mind adding a query that will do this? I checked the regexp_matches but I can't get the 'g' to work

Answer (score 0):

So this is not pure SQL but Postgresql, but this also does the job:

```
SELECT project,
       regexp_replace(address, '[^A-Za-z]', '', 'g') AS letters,
       regexp_replace(address, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') AS numbers
FROM repositories;
```